# how to see more than 5 labels in pie chart in tableau

Tags: tableau-api, pie-chart

I see only 5 labels even that i have 6 options - how can i solve it? the Malicious Bots are not shown in the labels.
[image]

Comment: if the answer has been provided and helped you, please accept it in order to mark the thread as closed.

Answer (score 2):

You can't see them because there no space available and so Tableau suggest you to not show it.

If you want to see it anyway, you can go to the Label mark of your worksheet, and check the flag "allow label to overlap".

[image]

Remember that selecting a specifc slice you can move the label, but I would not reccomend it if your chart may change due to filters.

Comment: ok - working. can i move the label in order not to overlap such as in excel you can move?

Comment: yes, as I wrote, you have to select a spcific slice (click) and then you can move the label as you prefer; if this solve your needs, please accept the solution in order to close this thread

Comment: 2 step operation. Click once on the label to select the label. Then press down on the selected label and you can reposition it as desired.